# Str To Int Python

Tags: python, integer

```
scores = int()
while True:
  score = int(input("Score: "))
  scores[int(score)] = score
  again = input("N/F")

  if again == "F":
    print('o')

  if again == "N":
    while True:
      score = int(input("Score: "))
      scores[int(score)] = score
      again = input("N/F")
    
  
      if again == "F":
        print(scores + score)
```

I don't know ho to make it int the `scores[int(score)] = score`
and I am getting that error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    scores[int(score)] = score
TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment
```

What Im trying to do its write your scores and calculate the average.
Thanks For Helping (:

Comment: what do you think `scores = int()` is doing?

Comment: Did you mean to have `scores = dict()`?

Comment: What you are doing is `scores = 0`. And then `0[int(score)]`. Python tells you it doesn't know what `0[...]` is supposed to mean.

Comment: `scores` is not an index-able object

Comment: what purpose does  `scores[int(score)] = score` serve? you already converted your input to int. And what exactly should `print(  scores + score  )` accomplish?  Please use a good tutorial to learn basic python usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to do something like this?

```
scores = []
while True:
    score = int(input("Score: "))
    scores.append(int(score))
    again = input("Continue? Y/N")

    if again.lower() == "n":
       break
print(f'Average: {sum(scores)/len(scores)}')
```

I think you would really benefit from a short beginner's tutorial on python before you start fiddling with toy apps like this. You will get a lot more benefit out of your practice if you at least know the basic syntax first, and I mean that with no mean spiritedness.

Answer (score 0):

```
scores = []
user_input = "0"
while user_input.isdigit():
    user_input = input("Type score or str to get result\n")
    if user_input.isdigit():
        scores.append(int(user_input))
mean = sum(scores)/len(scores) if len(scores)>0 else 0
```